# socket TCP/IP for HTTP communcation

Tags: sockets, network-programming, tcp

The following code is example  php code for socket tutorial, and I run successfully to collect remote site or localhost webpage.Either the protocol number I used for socket_create is 0 or 6, both
number is also working on that code, Why ? I thought network programming will needs to include TCP and IP for today's window computer together to make the communication possible. Why just need TCP or IP protocol num could make the program code working that doesn't include both protocol num ?
TCP is protocol for transport layer and IP is protocol for network layer for both OSI or classical TCP/IP model

```
              <?php
              $protocol = 'tcp';
              $get_prot = getprotobyname($protocol);
              echo $get_prot."----protocol\n";
              if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 6)))
              {
              $errorcode = socket_last_error();
              $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
              die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
               }
             echo "Socket created \n";
             if(!socket_connect($sock , '127.0.0.1' , 80))
             {
             $errorcode = socket_last_error();
             $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
             die("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
             }
             echo "Connection established \n";
             $message = "GET / HTTP/1.1   Accept:          text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8      \r\n\r\n";
             $message = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
             $message .= "Host: \r\n";
             $message .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
             //Send the message to the server
             if( ! socket_send ( $sock , $message , strlen($message) , 0))
             {
             $errorcode = socket_last_error();
             $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
             die("Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
             }
             echo "Message send successfully \n";
             //Now receive reply from server
             if(socket_recv ( $sock , $buf ,  6144 , MSG_WAITALL ) === FALSE)
             {
             $errorcode = socket_last_error();
             $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);
             die("Could not receive data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
              }
              //print the received message
              echo $buf;
              ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing 0 as the protocol will give you a default protocol. AF_INET says you want 
IP protocol suite (IPv4 specifically). For a combination of AF_INET and SOCK_STREAM, tcp is the default. A combination of AF_INET6 and SOCK_DGRAM would give you IPv6 and UDP as default.

TCP has the protocol number 6, which you can pass as well if you want to be explicit.

Comment: nos, thanks for your reply. My question why both also work either 0 (IPv4) or 6(TCP) ,and i thought TCP and IP needs work together for a communcation , please advise

Comment: nos, please review my question again and for manual of  socket_create you can read this site  at http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create.php, please advise

Comment: @aabb I don't understand what else you are asking. I already told you what 0 means. 0 does not mean IPv4. The 1. argument, AF_INET means IPv4.

Comment: thanks for your reply, 0 mean default protocol that depend on the computer default, for example, protocol default on window is TCP, Right  ?

Comment: Yes, TCP is the default for a combination of AF_INET and SOCK_STREAM, on virtually any operating system.